# Spring Shiro is not authenticating login screen in SpringMVC web application

Tags: security, mvc

I  am trying to use Apache Shiro framework 1.2.4 for security requirements of our Spring MVC web application.  I have included configuration details in the application context, pom.xml and web.xml below. The Shiro is not authenticating the user when user clicks the submit button on login scree.
Could you please let me know any solution to fix this issue?

ApplicationContext.xml

```
<bean id="dbdataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/Appweb" />
        </bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="POSTGRESQL" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dbdataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- spring based scanning for entity classes -->
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tracktrace.dao.jpa" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaRealm" class="com.appweb.security.JpaShiroRealm"></bean>
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" depends-on="jpaRealm">
    <property name="realm" ref="jpaRealm" />
    <property name="sessionMode" value="native"/>
</bean>
<bean id="lifecycleBeanPostProcessor" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.LifecycleBeanPostProcessor" />
<bean id="shiroFilter" class="org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean">
    <property name="securityManager" ref="securityManager" />
    <property name="loginUrl" value="/login"/>
    <property name="successUrl" value="/"/>
    <property name="unauthorizedUrl" value="/login"/>       
    <property name="filterChainDefinitions"> 
    <value>
        /login = authc
        /login.jsp = authc 
        /** = authc 
     </value> 

    </property>
</bean>
```

Web.xml
    Appweb Application

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.tracktrace.controller.common.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.tracktrace.controller.common.ApplicationListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/appContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>shiroEnvironmentClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.shiro.web.env.DefaultWebEnvironment</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Appweb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Appweb</servlet-name>
    <!-- <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern> -->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<filter>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>shiroFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-core</artifactId>
        <version>${shiro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-web</artifactId>
        <version>${shiro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-aspectj</artifactId>
        <version>${shiro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${shiro.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Login.jsp

```
<form action="">
user name:<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/>
password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
```

Remember Me:

Thank you in advance.